# Feed database MSSQL from export

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, entity-framework

I'm looking for a way to feed my Database. I use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to navigate through the database. I have many rows on many tables there.

I would like to find a fast way to export this database, and write a script which will feed database on my C# application. I often have to delete my DB and create it with entity framework migrations, and every time the DB is empty. I know it would be easy to do that just from MSSQL, but I want an automated way from code, so that when you start the application, it feeds the DB.

The DB is very big and entities are very complex, with many relationships between them, so I don't want to write a lone a json file which would contain everything. Hopefully there's a tool that can do this!

Comment: There are two ways this is typically handled. First (preferred), if you build your migrations as UPDATE/ALTER/INSERTs on an existing DB, instead of CREATE/INSERT, as you're doing now. Second: keep a reference DB in the development platform, and insert data from the reference DB. Exporting the data to load through the client code, as you've asked to do, is much slower, a lot more work to build and maintain, and more fragile.

Answer (score 1):

Best advise i have is writing a seeder that seeds data. Technically you could have it pull data from the MSSQL database but personally i would rather just write seeders that seed the data themselves without the need of a dependency on another service.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve this but as mentioned, you should seed the database. You can write a extension class for the `ModelBuilder`.

```
public static class ModelBuilderExtensions
{
    public static void Seed(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().HasData(
            new MyEntity
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Name = "SomeString",
                SomeValue = 3,
                IsSomething = true
            }
        );
    }
}
```

And within the context class, call the `Seed` method to populate the database.

```
public class MyContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities{ get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Seed();
    }
}
```

You can read more about data seeding [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding).